# How to set up nginx configuration site for django

Tags: django, nginx, nginx-config

I have a problem with nginx and django.

Config:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name 193.88.95.120;
    charset     utf-8;
    root /root/djangoprojects/megaproject;
    client_max_body_size 75M;
    location /media  {
        alias /root/djangoprojects/media/;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /root/djangoprojects/megapproject/megaapp/static/;
    }
   location / {
        include     /root/djangoprojects/megaproject/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Error 403 - forbidden.

When I create an index file in the project folder .html " - it opens.

But I need Django to work.

Please help me.